# Implement a counter on prolog towers of hanoi

Tags: prolog, counter, towers-of-hanoi

I have a program due in the morning using Prolog.

I am implementing Towers of Hanoi.

What I need help with is each time that it prints `Move disc number # from _ to _`. I need to increment a counter saying `Move X: "String"` String being the previous statement of what to move.

At the end of the program I need to print the total number of moves taken to accomplish the puzzle. I currently have my program setup recursively bottom-up.

Comment: It is always better to show some code.

Comment: It's hard to have any context to answer without seeing some relevant portion of your code.

Comment: Sorry guys, I will remember to post code next time. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common problem is keeping IO mixed with the calculation. It is better to isolate IO by having a wrapper predicate with an argument that becomes instantiated with the result.

Consider this (code is meant to demonstrate the addition of a counter, not solve the problem):

```
% one move
move(1,X,Y,_,_,1) :-                           
    write('Move top disk from '), 
    write(X), write(' to '), write(Y), nl.

move(N,X,Y,Z,Count,Counter) :- 
    N>1, 
    M is N-1,
    Countplus is Count*2,        % binary recursion tree
    move(M,X,Z,Y,Countplus,C1), 
    move(1,X,Y,_,Countplus,C2),
    move(M,Z,Y,X,Countplus,C3),
    Counter is C1+C2+C3.         % sum of moves

towers(N,X,Y,Z) :-
    Count is N*N-1,
    move(N,X,Y,Z,Count,Counter),                       
    % you can now do whatever you want with Counter, e.g. print it:
    write('The number of steps required with '),
    write(N), write(' disks is '), write(Count), write('.').
```

Even if the above code is not related to what you have, the same procedure applies: add arguments to transfer the Counter and use recursion to increment it.

Alternatively, there are [global variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%276.3%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/gvar.html%27%29%29) but are usually frowned upon as they are ease to misuse and write procedural programs.

Comment: format/2 is also useful to combine successive write/1 calls, for example: format("The number of steps required with ~w disks is ~w.", [N,Count]).

Answer (score 1):

instead of writting a do-all predicate, break it in do-one-thing predicates:

1. write a predicate that gets the number of discs and returns a list of moves that solve the problem (i.e. `[1->2, 3->1, ...]`)
2. the standard `length/2` predicate already allows you to count the number of moves on the list.
3. write a predicate to print the list of moves in an user friendly format.
4. write a predicate to call the previous predicates in order.

Answer (score 1):

Using this variant, one can call `hanoi(3,left,middle,right,Moves-NMoves)`, and a list of moves will be instantied to `Moves`, and the number of moves taken will be instantiated to `NMoves`. One can easily write a predicate to format each list member into Input/Output.

Notice how difference lists are utilized here to avoid the expensive use of `append/3`. The `length/2` call in the `hanoi/5` predicate acts as a sort of proof that the resulting list of moves is the correct size.

```
hanoi(N, Src, Aux, Dest, Moves-NMoves) :-
  NMoves is 2^N - 1,
  length(Moves, NMoves),
  move(N, Src, Aux, Dest, Moves-_).


move(1, Src, _, Dest, [Src->Dest|Rest]-Rest) :- !.
move(2, Src, Aux, Dest, [Src->Aux,Src->Dest,Aux->Dest|Rest]-Rest) :- !.
move(N, Src, Aux, Dest, Moves-Rest) :-
  N0 is N-1,
  move(N0, Src, Dest, Aux, Moves-M1),
  move(1, Src, Aux, Dest, M1-M2),
  move(N0, Aux, Src, Dest, M2-Rest).
```

A more readable approach could involve the use of DCG to hide the plumbing:

```
hanoi(N, Src, Aux, Dest, Moves-NMoves) :-
  NMoves is 2^N - 1,
  length(Moves, NMoves),
  phrase(move(N, Src, Aux, Dest), Moves).


move(1, Src, _, Dest) --> !,
  [Src->Dest].

move(2, Src, Aux, Dest) --> !,
  [Src->Aux,Src->Dest,Aux->Dest].

move(N, Src, Aux, Dest) -->
  { succ(N0, N) },
  move(N0, Src, Dest, Aux),
  move(1, Src, Aux, Dest),
  move(N0, Aux, Src, Dest).
```

Comment: Using a DCG to describe the list would make this much more readable.

Comment: @mat, that's a possibility. I added your suggestion as an alternative approach.